# Multiple deployment files with a single values file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am new to Helm and I want to create multiple deployments in k8s from a single deployment YAML file.
I've used a placeholder in the deployment.yaml like

```
metadata:
  name: job-{{ .Values.app.ujn }}
...
replicas: {{ .Values.app.replicas }}
```

and my values.yaml looks like

```
app:
  replicas: 10
  ujn: 1
---
app:
  replicas: 20
  ujn: 2
---
app:
  replicas: 30
  ujn: 3
```

The use case is something like that I want to create many deployment files with similar configuration but some params changed and I also don't want to make multiple values file for each deployment. Can I do something like that in the above example and create multiple files from a single values.yaml?

Also a follow up question, if I deploy this chart on the cluster and if I modify the number of deployments in next deploy, will helm delete the old ones or do those have to be deleted manually?

Comment: How are you differentiating when to use 10, 20, or 30 replicas? Usually this is required for different envs like dev, staging, prod.. in which case it is easier to create separate values files for each env. And during `helm install` you can specify the required values file.

Comment: in values.yaml, I'll have a unique identifier appended to the deployment name, which I have added in the example which will differentiate the deployment from each other.

Comment: I want to do n number of deployments for the same env

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you have puts multiple YAML *documents* into a single file.  It's unusual for tools to support this well (though `kubectl apply` and the output of Helm templates do support it); the most common case is that a tool will only read the first document.

Instead of having multiple documents, you can put a YAML list into the values file.

```yaml
# values.yaml
apps:
  - name: '1'
    replicas: 10
  - name: '2'
    replicas: 20
  - name: '3'
    replicas: 30
```

Then in your template file, you can use a `range` loop to loop over this.  Here Helm *does* support multiple documents in a single output stream, so you need to make sure each template begins with the YAML start-of-document marker.  Also remember that the `range` loop rebinds `.` so you may need different syntax for the top-level Helm objects like `.Values` or `.Release`, or if you call a helper template.

```yaml
{{- range $app := .Values.apps -}}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ $.Release.Name }}-job-{{ $app.name }}
  # labels: {{- include "mychart.labels" $ | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ $app.replicas }}
  template: { ... }
{{ end }}
```

Comment: can you please answer this:
if I deploy this chart on the cluster and if I modify the number of deployments in the next deploy, will helm delete the old ones, or do those have to be deleted manually?

Comment: If you delete something from the `apps:` list, then `helm upgrade` will delete it; if you add something, `helm upgrade` will create a new Deployment; if you change a replica count, Helm will update the replica count in-place.