# Possibility of downscale particular statefulset or deployment

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubernetes-statefulset

I want my kubedownscaler to downscale particular stateful set. Below is the config map i'm using.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: kube-downscaler
data:
DEFAULT_DOWNTIME: "Sat-Sun 00:00-06:30 Asia/Kolkata,Mon-Fri 15:33-15:43 Asia/Kolkata"
INCLUDE_RESOURCES: "deployments,horizontalpodautoscalers,statefulsets"
EXCLUDE_NAMESPACES: "kube-system, kube-downscaler, cert-manager, default, monitoring, operator, dev"
```

Here is it possible to add 3or4 statefulset

Or can I use just use one namespace like this <*INCLUDE_NAMESPACES: "test"*>

I tried this, but I was out of luck.

Comment: In kubernetes you can manage multiple resources using a single yaml file but if you want to manage manage resources of same type using a single yaml it's not possible you need to rely on something like helm charts. I'm attaching the references for you

1) [https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/)

2)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265303/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265303/multiple-deployment-files-with-a-single-values-file)

Comment: If you want to down scale a particular deployment you can follow the steps given in this [blog](https://www.padok.fr/en/blog/kube-downscaler)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details. I have checked the blog, but my requirement is it scale down deployments with specific name. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the Kube-Downscaler open source project here:
https://codeberg.org/hjacobs/kube-downscaler

I see that you already have some resources targeted to be downscaled so we won't touch them. Instead we will create a second deployment of the Kube Downscaler and we will call it `kube-downscaler-second`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    application: kube-downscaler-second
    version: v23.2.0
  name: kube-downscaler-second
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      application: kube-downscaler-second
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        application: kube-downscaler-second
        version: v23.2.0
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: kube-downscaler
      containers:
      - name: downscaler
        image: hjacobs/kube-downscaler:latest
        args:
          - --interval=60
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: kube-downscaler-second
              optional: true
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 100Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 5m
            memory: 100Mi
        securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1000
```

done that, remove the namespace we are going to target from the rule of the first kube-downscaler. Then, in order to target only the StatefulSets present in the "test-namespace", you need to give only that namespace as a target. You can do something like that using this regex inside the `EXCLUDE_NAMESPACES` environment variable of the ConfigMap.

```
^(?!test-namespace).*$
```

If you have additional statefulsets inside that namespace that you don't want to scale down you can insert them inside the `EXCLUDE_DEPLOYMENTS` environment variable (that despite its name, it works for every type of resource)

Your config map should look like something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: kube-downscaler-second
data:
DEFAULT_DOWNTIME: "Sat-Sun 00:00-06:30 Asia/Kolkata,Mon-Fri 15:33-15:43 Asia/Kolkata"
INCLUDE_RESOURCES: "statefulsets"
EXCLUDE_NAMESPACES: "^(?!test-namespace).*$"
EXCLUDE_DEPLOYMENTS: statefulset-hello,statefulset-world
```

This should work, let me know!